# How to detect non-errors in powershell without Try-Catch?

Tags: powershell

In case of an error on `Remove-Item`, due to missing directory, $error returns

```
Cannot find path 'D:\Downloads\MissingDirectory' because it doe
s not exist.
```

I want to detect a *non-error* condition. Using simple `erroraction` switch, this doesn't work:

```
$error.clear()
Remove-Item -recurse -force $DirName -erroraction 'SilentlyContinue'
if ($error -eq '') {$NumOK++}
```

Comment: [1] have you tried inducing an error, confirming that `$Error` contains something ... and then testing your `$Error -eq ''`? that test fails to give ANY response for me in ps5.1 on win10. ///// [2] PLEASE, change your abbreviations to the full text in your command. having to look up what you are posting is ... unkind of you. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, i can induce an error. In that case, $error resolves to a string containing a description of the error.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey are you saying $Error returns nothing if you raise an error? Case matters.

Comment: i think this might be that $error doesn't necessarily return a string in a non-error condition. I may need to understand the structure of $error better -- sometimes it's seems to be an array. The default property might not be what i think...

Comment: I expect `$Error.count` doesn't work?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Your comment helped me find the answer, but not the way you meant. I checked the type and length of `$error` in a non-error condition.

Comment: @johnywhy - my intent was that the `$Error` collection is a _collection_ ... and doing `$Error -eq ''` means `is there an item in the collection that is equal to an empty string` ... and there is no normal way to get an empty string into the `$Error` collection. [*grin*] your test >>> `$Error -eq ''` <<< will ALWAYS return nothing/null, and that will map to `$False`. so your test was ALWAYS returning `$False` no matter what was in `$Error` ... even when the collection contained at least one error. ///// in any case, i am glad that you figured it out! [*grin*]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the `$?` automatic variable.

> "$?  Contains the execution status of the last command. It contains
> True if the last command succeeded and False if it failed."
>
> [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#long-description)

It's not necessary to clear errors first.

```
Remove-Item -recurse -force $DirName -erroraction 'SilentlyContinue'
if ($?) {$NumOK++}
```

Comment: this answer is superior to a similar answer which received 2 upvotes, because the other answer: Doesn't link to it's source, includes superfluous `= True`, and includes superfluous `$LastExitCode`.

Comment: Because all you did was copy my post, edit it slightly, and mark it as the answer. Your essentially just trying to give yourself credit for someone else's work lol.

Comment: @NickW. No, your answer has specific flaws that i listed, which you declined to fix. You didn't link to your source, included superfluous `= True`, includes superfluous `$LastExitCode`, and formatted a quote as code. If you had made those fixes, i would have marked yours as answer. As it stands, your answer has flaws which aren't up to SO standards. Speaking of copy/paste, someone else posted your answer before you posted it. They since deleted it. You used their same verbiage "...this is the perfect use-case for..."

Comment: @NickW. If you apply my four edits, i'll gladly remove my answer and mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the perfect use-case for the $? automatic variable.

```
#Setup the needed information
New-Variable -Debug:$False -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$False -Verbose:([Bool]($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue') -as [Bool]) -Name DoVerbose     -Value ([Bool]($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue') -as [Bool])
New-Variable -Debug:$False -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$False -Verbose:$DoVerbose  -Name DoConfirm -Value ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean([System.Convert]::ToInt16(($ConfirmPreference -ne [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::None -and $ConfirmPreference -le [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::High)-1)*-1))
New-Variable -Debug:$False -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$False -Verbose:$DoVerbose  -Name DoDebug -Value ([Bool]($DebugPreference -eq 'Continue') -as [Bool])

New-Variable -Debug:$DoDebug -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$DoConfirm -Verbose:$DoVerbose -Name NumOK         -Value ([Int]::Parse('0') -as [Int])
New-Variable -Debug:$DoDebug -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$DoConfirm -Verbose:$DoVerbose -Name DirName       -Value ([System.io.DirectoryInfo]"C:\SomeFolder" -as [System.io.DirectoryInfo])

#Perform the action
Remove-Item -Debug:$DoDebug -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$DoConfirm -Verbose:$DoVerbose -Recurse -Path ([System.io.DirectoryInfo]$DirName.FullName -as [System.io.DirectoryInfo]).fullname -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
if (([Bool]::Parse($?) -as [Bool]) -eq ([Bool]::TrueString -as [Bool])) {
    Set-Variable -Debug:$DoDebug -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference -Force -Confirm:$DoConfirm -Verbose:$DoVerbose -Name NumOK -Value (([Int]::Parse($NumOK) -as [Int]) + ([Int]1 -as [Int]))
} Else {
    Write-Verbose -Message 'Unable to remove item.' -Debug:$DoDebug -Verbose:$DoVerbose
}

Write-Host -Debug:$DoDebug -Object "$([String]::Format([String]$NumOK.ToString(),{0:0}))" -Verbose:$DoVerbose
```

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1): `about_Automatic_Variables`

> $? Contains the execution status of the last command. It contains True
> if the last command succeeded and False if it failed.
>
> For cmdlets and advanced functions that are run at multiple stages in
> a pipeline, for example in both process and end blocks, calling
> this.WriteError() or $PSCmdlet.WriteError() respectively at any point
> will set $? to False, as will this.ThrowTerminatingError() and
> $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()....
>
> For native commands (executables), $? is set to True when
> $LASTEXITCODE is 0, and set to False when $LASTEXITCODE is any other
> value.
>
> Note: Until PowerShell 7, containing a statement within parentheses
> (...), subexpression syntax $(...) or array expression @(...) always
> reset $? to True, so that (Write-Error) shows $? as True. This has
> been changed in PowerShell 7, so that $? will always reflect the
> actual success of the last command run in these expressions.

Comment: Almost acceptable. I would link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables (this gives more information than the plain text helpfile)

Comment: Also, you don't have to say `($? -eq $True)`. That's redundant. You can just say `($?)`. I would make the edits, but your "Suggested edit queue is full".

Comment: @johnywhy I know, but I prefer it for clarity sake.

Comment: $LastExitCode is superfluous info.

Comment: Here's an example from Khan Academy, where they do NOT use `= True` with a conditional boolean: `var belowFreezing = temperature < 32;
if (belowFreezing) {...` They DON'T say "if (belowFreezing = True". That would be equivalent to saying "If True = True". https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/ap-computer-science-principles/programming-101/boolean-logic/a/conditionals-with-if-else-and-booleans

Comment: Not marked as answer because: Doesn't link to your info source, includes superfluous `= True`, and includes superfluous `$LastExitCode`. – johny why just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: Would be better to use quote-formatting for a quote, instead of code-formatting.

Comment: From Stanford University: "Another way to write the if-statement uses `== true` like this: `if (bear.isMother() == true) {...` But it is not the best style. The `== true` adds nothing, since the if-statement itself already checks if the test is true. Therefore, it is better to write: `if (bear.isMother()) {...` https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs108/cs108.1082/106a-java-handouts/HO32IfBoolean.pdf

Comment: @johnywhy Made some edits, hopefully it better suits your preferences.

Answer (score -2):

In error condition, `$error` is an arraylist. The default return value of `$error` is `$error[0]`, which contains a description of the error.

In the case of a non-error condition, $error array has a length of `null`. Therefor, test for a length of null.

```
if ($error.Length -eq $null) {
# non-error actions here
}
```